# Uploading umbraco site on server from local host

Tags: file-upload, content-management-system, hosting, localhost, umbraco

I've successfully created site using Umbraco now its time to upload it on hosting server..
i've searched and got one paid product for the same..and i dont want to use it.

Has any body tried developing Umbraco site on local and then uploading it on server?

If yes then please help me doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I run the umbraco install from a local IIS website. Then I setup my visual studio solution for that website (and my souce control). Then I work, until I reach a beta version, then I go through this process for deploying:

1. Ftp over to the remove website and copy the whole website (I actually use Beyond compare).
2. Connect to my local database with management studio and create a .bak file.
3. Upload the .bak file to the database server.
4. Restore that database
5. Review connection strings in web.config

Then I'm pretty much done.

Once I'm "live" and have content I don't want to lose, when I want to work on the website, I bring back the live database through a .bak file, then I make my changes. They often include DB changes since the schema is basically in the database. I note all the operations I do. Once my changes are ready I manually replicate the changes on the live site as I update the files.

This is very painfull but I tried solutions like courrier and other things like that and they are not reliable enough for production I find. Manually is the only risk free way I see for the moment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that happens all the time. Use FTP to copy your local installation to your webserver, modify the web.config to point to the correct database and your website should be up-and-running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions with less clicks but here's how I do it on azure websites with sql, not sure what hosting/db you're using:
1) Create an empty db on azure with the same login and user as my local db.
2) Create an empty site on azure connected to my db.
3) Download the publishing profile.
4) Upload the db the first time with [Sql Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).
5) Import the publishing profile into and upload the site with [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).
6) Thereafter I deploy the site and db with WebMatrix.

WebMatrix uses WebDeploy or FTP, you can use WebDeploy through IIS if you like, and FTP.