# Umbraco 7 Source Control - File Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to find a way to manage Umbraco files in source control on a small team. When trying to add templates and document types to Umbraco, they are added to both the local SDF file and the MVC project. However, if we do not deploy the SDF file with those changes, the new template will appear in the MVC project but not the Back Office. Ideally we would like templates (and things related to this) managed in source control, and have content not be deployed as that should be added per environment. We do not want to manage an SDF file, and would like to have this as clean as possible for multiple people to be working on at the same time.

Has anybody found a clean solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at a package like [uSync for Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync) it's quite useful for sharing this sort of stuff in a shared development environment and should cater for most of the requirements you outlined.

> uSync sits in you Umbraco site - it justs a dll - and will write
>   database objects out to disk, and when the site starts it will read
>   the files of the disk and update the Umbraco database to keep
>   everything in sync.
>
> uSync will read/write out:
>
> - DocumentTypes
> - MediaTypes
> - DataTypes
> - Macros
> - DictionaryItems
> - Languages
> - Stylesheets
> - Templates*

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what we were looking for and works great.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no short answer. These types of issues are difficult to find a quick and easy way to work around. You can read-up here [Uploading umbraco site on server from local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177582/uploading-umbraco-site-on-server-from-local-host/15297435#15297435) I posted an answer to a similar subject.

Basically what I find is the smoothest is that I simply manually re-do the changes I want on my live. It's time consuming, but it's the only sure way I found of getting everything in there and making sure it's correctly deployed. Specially on a live site.

Local databases (I don't use compact edition), tend to always be out of sync, so periodically, I take the "master" (or live) db and back it up. Send it to my devs so they can update. And download the media files also, share them over the network.

Our source control is TFS, in there I commit "EVERYTHING", dlls and umbraco files. I find that this is the easiest way to get a new dev setup locally and quickly.

Hope this helps.